# Why does adding a parameterless constructor to my entity model class work here? What are the implications?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics, constructor

So I have this office entity class:

```
[Table("office_entity")]
public class EFOffice : EFBusinessEntity
{

    [Column("address")]
    [StringLength(250)]
    public string Address { get; set; }

    [Column("business_name")]
    [StringLength(150)]
    public string BusinessName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<EFEmployee> Employees { get; set; }

    public EFOffice(Guid id, Guid tenantId, string address, string businessName)
    {
        this.Id = id;
        this.TenantId = tenantId;
        this.Address = address;
        this.BusinessName = businessName;
    }
}
```

I'm implementing a generic repository, and I just added this method that checks if an entity already exists in the repository:

```
public bool Exists<TEntity>(Guid key) where TEntity : class, IBusinessEntity
{
    return (_context.Set<TEntity>().Find(key) != null);
}
```

Then I wrote the following test code:

```
public void TestExists1()
{
    InitializeDatabase();
    EFOffice testOffice = InitializeOffice1();
    Debug.Assert(EFRepo.Exists<EFOffice>(testOffice.Id));
}
```

The method for InitializeOffice1() is as follows:

```
private EFOffice InitializeOffice1()
{
    EFOffice newOffice = new EFOffice(SparkTest.TestGuid1, SparkTest.TestGuid2, "Generic Address", "HQ");
    return newOffice;
}
```

The test is supposed to pass because I already inserted the office returned by InitializeOffice1() previously. However, I get the following error:

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: The class 'Models.Employees.EF.EFOffice' has no parameterless constructor.

So then I added this to the EFOffice class shown at the top:

```
private EFOffice()
{

}
```

And for some reason the test now passes. Can anyone explain what's going on? And does having a parameterless constructor have bad side effects? It's important that every office I insert has an id, a tenantId, an address and a businessName, as listed in the constructor at the top.

Comment: What's the code that's trying to create an object from the parameterless constructor?  Clearly the code you've shown isn't trying to, but it's calling some code elsewhere that is.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

All Entities linked to EntityFramework must have a Default Constructor.

When Entity Framework maps from a database query to your Entities use the default constructor to instantiate a new instance of your Entity to fill it with the data retrieved from your database.

If you don't have a default constructor Entity Framework doesn't know how to create an instance of it and throws the exception

> The class 'Models.Employees.EF.EFOffice' has no parameterless constructor.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know that. So I should probably do the same for all my other entity classes. Thanks!

Comment: @Drew , Yes you need it for all your other entity classes.

Comment: And is the way I did it in my post correct? Using private instead of public, and leaving it empty? Sorry, I'm not too familiar with this stuff.

Comment: It has to be public or protected https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd468057.aspx

Comment: I just be googling and It seems that it's possible to have private constructor http://thedatafarm.com/data-access/entity-framework-private-constructors-and-private-setters/ . But be careful thre is some side effect it seems http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9907731/private-constructor-on-poco-entity-preventing-eager-loding  . If you want your constructed as public, set as protected

Comment: I see, I'll add protected to each of my default constructors :) thanks

Comment: Short, simple and clear, yet so hard to find this answer through google